# How to have Gnuplot automatically updating .eps figures on mac?

Tags: macos, gnuplot

Once I edit and run my gnuplot scripts on Ubuntu and I have my .eps figure open, I can see the new figure updated. However, on Mac OSx I have to close and open the file, to see the updated figure. How to see the updated figures once I run the edited script?

Comment: That’s not an issue of Gnuplot, that’s a missing feature of your EPS viewer.

Comment: What tool are you using to view the `.eps` files?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac the problem is that Preview converts .eps to .pdf before displaying, and this process gets in the way of Preview watching the file.

I like the Skim tool for viewing .eps that I generate with gnuplot or latex. It will prompt you the first time the file changes if you want to follow it.

Another (less than ideal on Mac) workaround is to open the file in `gv`, and select the option State > Watch file.

I would love to hear about tools in OS X that do this automatically...

Comment: For latex I use `pdflatex` and the same idea explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Preview. I got the point. As @andyras explained Preview converts `.eps` to `.pdf` before open the file, and that's the problem. So, I've just created a small script that runs my gnuplot script,  converts the `.eps` to `.pdf` and open the pdf file with Preview, that simple. Running this script instead of the gnuplot script, I have the `.eps` 'automatically' updated.

```
    gnuplot plot
    epstopdf Structures.eps 
    open  Structures.pdf
```