# Gnuplot: {/Symbol s} not working, even with "set terminal postscript eps enhanced"

Tags: gnuplot

My goal is to place a lowercase sigma character in the x-axis of a plot created by Gnuplot and output in eps format.

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output 'myplot.eps'
set key
xoffset = 0.1
set size 0.65
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
set xlabel "{/Symbol s}"
set ylabel "log (k)"
set style data points
plot "mydata.txt" index 0 using 2:1 pt 2 title "Data1", \
    "mydata.txt" index 1 using 2:1 pt 6 title "Data2."
```

Based on my reading, I believe the above should work.  Yet, the x-axis remains unlabeled.  The y-axis is properly labeled.

If the below is used instead, the x-axis is labeled "9".  I still do not get sigma.

```
set xlabel "{/Symbol \\229}"
```

Comment: Which gnuplot do you have and how do you view the EPS file?

Comment: I have gnuplot version 5.0 patchlevel 5.  I am viewing the EPS file with Preview version 9.0 (909.12).

Comment: Probably a problem with Preview, see e.g. my comments to http://stackoverflow.com/q/25736904/2604213, http://stackoverflow.com/q/40824152/2604213 and furthermore http://stackoverflow.com/a/29089378/2604213 which suggests Skim as alternative viewer.

Comment: Ok, to test this idea, I used LaTeX to add the eps file to a pdf.  The sigma symbol was *properly displayed* in the pdf generated by LaTeX, even when viewed with Preview.  In fact, my main goal was to use the eps file as part of a LaTeX document, and this works.  Thank you.  It looks like I will need to install Skim as an alternative viewer if I want to preview the eps images before including them in LaTeX.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also use `pdfcairo` or `cairolatex` as terminals

Comment: Yes.  My understanding, however, is that pdfcairo and cairolatex both provide output as pdf.  The journal to which I am submitting a manuscript with LaTeX prefers that graphics be provided in eps format.  Why not use epslatex, then?  I don't know the full answer to how one uses epslatex.  I get that you need `set terminal epslatex monochrome` followed by `set output 'myfile.tex'`, and that formatting has to change for the text commands within gnuplot.  `set xlabel '$\sigma$'`.  You get a .tex and an .eps file as output.  I don't know how to make the two files work together to make the chart.

Comment: If the journal requires eps, ok. `cairolatex` can output either pdf or eps. For a general workflow with cairolatex or epslatex, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20347095/2604213.

Comment: I wonder if there is more to using epslatex than just what is in the link above.  When I add the system commands calling latex and dvips, I get some errors: (1) .dvi cannot be opened.  No such file.  (2) No configuration file gnuplot.cfg found.

Comment: No, if you used *exactly* that script in the linked answer it should work fine. That dvi cannot be opened means that the previous call to latex failed for some reason